# How to write a tilde with vertical line?

Tags: math-mode, tilde

I want to write an tilde with an vertical line like [image: tilde with vert. line]

thank you for your help :)

Where i found it:
[image]

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb}
\def\vTilde{\mathbin{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\mkern-1.5mu\vert}{\sim}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
a \mathbin{\vTilde} b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: What does this symbol mean?

Comment: I have this symbol in my Script for the Reiter Default-Logic Inferencerelation

Comment: From that image it mostly looks like a `\mathord{\vert}` and a `\mathord{\sim}` kerned at bit together.

Comment: Not really satisfying but nevertheless thx

Comment: At least from the orginal image it is quite obvious that it is not a designed symbols, but rather two symbols on top of each other.

Comment: oh okay, idk realy

Comment: @FelixO Please, look at the last picture in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply `|\kern-0.48em\sim`?

---

### [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Reiter'schen Inferezrelation 
$|\kern-0.48em\sim_\Delta^{Reiter}$ 
aus W ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't the space around `\sim` stretchable (it's a binary relation) so your `0.48em` might not always be correct. That was why I suggested `\mathord{\sim}` in a comment.

Comment: As @daleif says. Also, `\mathord` is actually redundant: Merely enclosing something in braces turns it into an ordinary math atom. And I think it's more common to use `\mkern` with `mu` units in this situation. (Neither of these comments is very important.)

Comment: Right, both, but it is like putting the band-aid before the wound. The issue  is (apparently) is only  a single inline symbol.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen it is also meant more as a guide to the user. Most people does not know that `{\sim}` is actually the same as `\mathord{\sim}`

Comment: Sorry, but this is very suboptimal. This symbol should be a `\mathrel`. More important, with the current code, the space between `|` and `\sim` is flexible, so in an inline formula you may (actually you will) not get the desired result.

Comment: @Fran I added an example that shows why your proposal is really suboptimal.

Comment: @egreg I already recognized to previous commenters  that it could not work well in some other scenario than a  single inline symbol. The question for me is if the OP need more than a  single inline symbol, and if this is enough, if just a `\kern` could be reasonable or one can expect troubles too often, or at least problems tan cannot have a simple fix as put the symbol inside a `\mbox`

Answer (score 5):

A first approximation would be

```
\mathrel{|}\joinrel\sim
```

but it's not perfect:

[image]

Since `\joinrel` is

```
\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}
```

we can adjust the thing to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rdfli}{\mathrel{|\mkern-3.6mu}\sim}

\begin{document}

$\rdfli_{\Delta}^{\mathrm{Reiter}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the symbol also in subscripts or superscripts, you need to adjust the backing up in the different math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rdfli}{\mathrel{|\rdflibackup}\sim}
\newcommand{\rdflibackup}{\mathchoice{\mkern-3.6mu}{\mkern-3.6mu}{\mkern-4mu}{\mkern-4.5mu}}

\begin{document}

$\rdfli_{\Delta}^{\mathrm{Reiter}}$

$\scriptstyle\rdfli_{\Delta}^{\mathrm{Reiter}}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\rdfli_{\Delta}^{\mathrm{Reiter}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that this will need fixes if different fonts are used. For instance, with NewTX it might be

```
\newcommand{\rdflibackup}{\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{\mkern-3.5mu}{\mkern-3.9mu}{\mkern-3.9mu}}
```

[image]

#### Addition.

Let's compare my proposal with the other one by Fran.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\newcommand{\rdfli}{\mathrel{|\rdflibackup}\sim}
\newcommand{\rdflibackup}{\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{\mkern-3.5mu}{\mkern-3.9mu}{\mkern-3.9mu}}

\begin{document}

Here is a paragraph where we use $\rdfli_{\Delta}^{\mathrm{Reiter}}\varphi$ and also
$|\kern-0.48em\sim_\Delta^{\mathrm{Reiter}}\varphi$ to see whether the~symbols are good
in context.

\end{document}
```

I admit to have cheated a bit, but just to emphasize the problem: with Fran's proposal, there is flexible space between `|` and `\sim`, whose effect can be clearly seen in the picture.

[image]

Comment: A tiny caveat: The backing up will likely need adjusting if you use a different font.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, I intended to add it, but the glass of wine in the train distracted me. ;-)